# Combining large number of independent probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to calculate likelihood of laser scan($Z$) at give pose($x$) with known map ($m$) using beam based model

$P\left(z_t|x_t,m \right)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}P'\left(z_i|x_t,m \right)$

My scan has 360 rays i.e $n=360$, When i calculate $P\left(z_t|x_t,m \right)$ it becomes zero as multiplication of 360 propabilities $<1.$

My query is how to combine all 360 probabilities to normalised($0$ to $1$) and not zero probability.

Thanks.

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/4573/laser-beam-based-model-probability-in-case-of-single-particle).

Answer (score 1):

It may seem a naive answer, but have you tried this calculation using the fact that the logarithm of a product is the sum of the logarithms? So that the logarithm of the probability you are looking for is the sum of the logarithms of the 360 probabilities?

Comment: Thanks for reply, At the end when change them to probability they are near to zero($2^{-150}$ or $10^{-150}$). I am looking for a way which gives probability 0 to 1.

Comment: Entropy might me better and like to know other options available.